# How to access re-raised exception in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

In Python 3, there's a [useful `raise ... from ...` feature](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/08/03/the-most-underrated-feature-in-python-3/) to re-raise an exception. That said, how do you find the original (/ re-raised) exception from the raised exception? Here's a (silly) example with comments to demonstrate what I mean--

```
def some_func():
    try:
      None() # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    except as err:
      raise Exception("blah") from err

try:
    some_func()
except as err:
    # how can I access the original exception (TypeError)?
```

Comment: BTW: using `from` is mostly useful when doing `raise Exception("blah") from None` which tells python to *hide* that `TypeError` and make it unaccesible. *By default* the `TypeError` is already stored in the new exception (that's why you see the `During handling of the above exception blah` message in tracebacks) so doing `raise ... from err` is mostly useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the `__cause__` attribute of the raised exception. Taken from the [docs on the `raise` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) it says regarding `raise ... from ...`:

> The `from` clause is used for exception chaining: if given, the second expression must be another exception class or instance, *which will then be attached to the raised exception as the `__cause__` attribute* (which is writable). If the raised exception is not handled, both exceptions will be printed.

So, in your given scenario, `repr`ing the `__cause__` attribute:

```
def some_func():
    try:
      None() # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    except TypeError as err:
      raise Exception("blah") from err

try:
    some_func()
except Exception as er:
    print(repr(er.__cause__))
```

Will print out:

```
TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",)
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever an exception is raised from an exception handler (the `except` clause), the original exception will bestored in new exception's `__context__`.

Whenever an exception is raised using `from` syntax, the exception specified in `from` will be saved in the `__cause__` attribute of the new exception.

In the usual use case, that amounts to both `__cause__` and `__context__` containing the original exception:

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception('first exception')
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('second exception') from e

try:
    f()
except Exception as e:
    print('This exception', e)
    print('Original exception', e.__context__)
    print('Also original exception', e.__cause__)
```

Here is also an example of when `__context__` is set:

```
try:
    raise Exception('first exception')
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception('second exception')
```

and an example of when `__cause__` is set:

```
e = Exception('first exception')
raise Exception('second exception') from e
```

Comment: Ahh, neat. Did not know about `__context__`.